# Convert list of matrices to a data.frame with row.names as names of list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices called `list1` with the following structure:

```
$ENSLAFT00000000003
     start end
[1,]   360 360
[2,]   394 394

$ENSLAFT00000000011
     start end
[1,]    15  15

$ENSLAFT00000000020
     start end
[1,]    45  45

$ENSLAFT00000000023
     start end

$ENSLAFT00000000024
     start  end
[1,]    13   13
[2,]   369  369
[3,]   602  602
[4,]   775  775
[5,]   983  983
[6,]  1200 1200
[7,]  1491 1491
```

Some of the items are empty but I would like to transform this list into a data.frame with two columns and the following structure:

```
ID                         pos
ENSLAFT00000000003         360
ENSLAFT00000000003         394
ENSLAFT00000000011          15
ENSLAFT00000000020          45
ENSLAFT00000000024          13
ENSLAFT00000000024         369
ENSLAFT00000000024         602
ENSLAFT00000000024         775
ENSLAFT00000000024         983
ENSLAFT00000000024        1200
ENSLAFT00000000024        1491
```

ENSLAFT00000000023 was omitted in the output as it was an empty matrix in the initial list.

I can somewhat get the desired structure but without keeping the rowname identity by using:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, e)[,1])
```

But I am still lacking to keep the rownames, which are needed.

Do you have any suggestions for doing this data transformation in R?

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

We extract the 'start' element by looping over the `list` and `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
out <- stack(lapply(lst1, \(x) {
          st <- x[,"start"]
          if(length(st) == 0) st <- NA_real_
          st
            }))[2:1]
names(out) <- c("ID", "pos")
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, just a question, does the `\(x)` mean "function(x)"?

Comment: @Alexis Yes, it is a concise option in `base R` from the recent R version

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(list1, ~ select(as.data.frame(.x), start)) %>%
  enframe %>%
  unnest(value,keep_empty = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
  name               start
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 ENSLAFT00000000003   360
2 ENSLAFT00000000003   360
3 ENSLAFT00000000011    15
4 ENSLAFT00000000023    NA
```

**Data**

```
list1 <- list(ENSLAFT00000000003 = structure(c(360, 360, 394, 394), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))), ENSLAFT00000000011 = structure(c(15, 
15), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))), 
    ENSLAFT00000000023 = structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(0L, 2L
    ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))))
```

Comment: I guess you need to change those elements having 0 rows to NA

Comment: what i meant is `map(lst1, ~ .x[, "start"]) %>% enframe %>% unnest(value, keep_empty = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::imap_dfr` (I am using @AndrewGillreath-Brown's data, to whom I thank):

```r
library(tidyverse)

imap_dfr(l, ~ bind_cols(ID = .y, pos = if (nrow(.x) == 0) NA else .x[,"start"]))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   ID                   pos
#>   <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 ENSLAFT00000000003   360
#> 2 ENSLAFT00000000003   360
#> 3 ENSLAFT00000000011    15
#> 4 ENSLAFT00000000023    NA
```